# Normalization of 4-velocity using an arbitrary parameter (not proper time)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, geodesics

The normalization of the 4-velocity vector is

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-1
\end{equation}
I understand that if we parametrize the curve with some arbitrary parameter $\lambda$ then we'd get

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}=C
\end{equation}

I have two questions about this:

1. Does $C$ depend on the spacetime we are in? or in the initial coordinates of the path choosen? Is it the same for all paths in that spacetime? What is the dependence of $C$?
2. Does this normalization hold for any timelike path $x^\mu(\lambda)$, geodesic or not?

Answer (score 2):

- $\pm C >0 $ iff the signature is $(\pm,\mp,\mp,\mp)$, respectively.
- $\pm C = (\frac{d\tau}{d\lambda})^2$, where $\tau$ is [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time).
- Apart from the signature, $C$ is arbitrary. It is not necessarily constant, and not necessary the same for different timelike curves, even if it is a geodesic.